# Weird behaviour in localhost:3000 after publishing the site on Github Pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, localhost

I've a trouble after publishing my portfolio website online into the Github pages.
Before the published it works just fine but when I publish this and then I want to update some data into website I see all the website visual-effect fully spoiled.

I also create another **folder and bring the all files and code into new folder** but it also looks like the same.

local host:3000
error into the "console" [localhost broken img-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3khmd.png), [fully broken styles and fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPYdp.png).

```
Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: http://localhost:3000/portfolio/logo192.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)
```

Here the published website link [here it looks like fine into github how that should be look like](https://anujpanwar01.github.io/portfolio/)

Source code
[on github](https://github.com/anujpanwar01/portfolio)

Comment: Perhaps you have `localhost:3000` hardcoded somewhere?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information and code. Links to off-site services are fine as supplementary information but everything required to understand your question should be here. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I rechecked my code and remove the styles.css from public folder and also delete the link of css in html.
And import it into "index.js" and works just fine.